# Twiiter4J Filter Tweets and Rate Limit Issue

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am new to Twitter API. I am using Java and Twitter4J for development.

Requirement is:

**Setup a Crone job which will fetch HomeTimline/tweets of users and filter the tweets based on some keywords and store into database**

So, i have used `getHomeTimeline()` function of twitter4J and fetching 100 tweets. Currently my crone job executes every one minute perform the task.

After some time i am getting following error.

```
429:Returned in API v1.1 when a request cannot be served due to the application's rate 

limit having been exhausted for the resource. See Rate Limiting in API v1.1.(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1)
message - Rate limit exceeded
code - 88

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=e5488403 or
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0a410619
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[e5488403-0a410619], statusCode=429, message=Rate limit exceeded, code=88, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remaining=0, limit=15, resetTimeInSeconds=1375947321, secondsUntilReset=1137}, version=3.0.3}
```

As per error message my application's rate limit is over.
But when i get rate limit of my application using below code

```
RateLimitStatus rateLimit = twitter.getRateLimitStatus("application").get("/application/rate_limit_status");
System.out.println("Application Remaining RateLimit ="+rateLimit.getRemaining());
```

This display that remaining limit is around 150. Hoever if you refer the exception above in last lime it shows `limit=15`.

In one of the twitter document i rad that for application rate limit is 180 request per 15 minutes.

- Please guide me to resolve this error.
- If i fetch 100 result does it counts a single hit or more than one?
- Does Twiiter4J use Streaming API or REST API?
- What would be better approach for this requirement?

Please help

Comment: Did u get any solution?

Comment: Actually, I just fetch current remaining limit from Twitter and if it is not zero then i don't make call. I have to implement this logic right now. May this help you